# hudson and jenkins parameterized trigger plugin - running the same job multiple times with different parameters

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I'm trying to run the same job multiple times with different parameters via a parent job. However, only the first of the triggered jobs runs.

The parent job has the checkbox "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" checked, and there are two triggers created, each with a different parameter value for a parameter x on the downstream job. Job 1 has x=1, Job 2 has x=2. Only job 1 is run!?

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running newer Jenkins/plugin versions than mentioned here? https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8985

Comment: Running the latest version of the plugin, we're running Hudson ver. 2.0.1. Perhaps the plugin works, but the Hudson core not so much?

Comment: Updated Hudson to 2.1.1 and the plugin to 2.4. Doesn't work :(

Comment: From a quick check, it appears that this bug was only reported to and fixed in Jenkins core and the plugin, not in Hudson. Fortunately, upgrading to Jenkins is seamless, and recommended by StackOverflow users ;) http://stackoverflow.com/q/4973981/

Comment: looks like you are right, I installed jenkins and it works fine. the guys running hudson don't want to upgrade and say jenkins is a dead codebase :(

Comment: Weird. It's the opposite. Jenkins continues to produce a new release every single week; they've had 2-3x the number of commits as Hudson in the last two weeks. Maybe the new Jenkins stable release will convince your admins :) https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/LTS+Release+Line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Hudson.

It was reported to Jenkins and fixed there, both in the core and this particular plugin several months ago.

See also the [Jenkins vs Hudson discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4973981/) on StackOverflow for further reasons to upgrade to Jenkins.