# How to get hudson's git plugin to clone repo with the name of the repo in the path?

Tags: git, version-control, hudson

Let's say I have a repo called "stuff".  git@github.com:mine/stuff.git

when I do a git clone of this repo from the command line, it creates a directory called "stuff" and puts everything in that directory.

When I set up hudson to use git, it puts everything in the directory

```
$hudson_home/jobs/myjob/workspace/*
```

with no "stuff" after workspace.  Just the items inside of stuff.

How can I make hudson clone the repo like the commandline does, namely:

```
$hudson_home/jobs/myjob/workspace/stuff/*
```

I see no options for this and I do not want to change the default workspace path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether this feature is in Hudson, since I have [upgraded to Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4973981/).

But if you click "Advanced" at the *bottom* of the Git section (there are two "Advanced" buttons), there is a property called "Local subdirectory for repo" which does what you want.