# ImportError when running Python script in Jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, gearman

I have a Python script that I want to run as part of a Jenkins project.  When I try to run the script via Jenkins, I get an ImportError when it tries to find the gearman module.  (Yes, the gearman module is installed on the slave node - I am able to run an interactive Python shell and can successfully import this module.)

This is the exact error:

```
+ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gearman, time, sys
ImportError: No module named gearman
```

How do I let Jenkins know where to look for modules?  Thanks!

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995809/jenkins-putting-my-python-module-on-the-pythonpath

Comment: I already tried setting a build step (Python script):
`
import sys
import os
# jenkins exposes the workspace directory through env.
sys.path.append(os.environ['WORKSPACE'])
import gearman`

And it fails on the import.

Comment: See my answer below. Try setting your PYTHONPATH in the build step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's much more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995809/jenkins-putting-my-python-module-on-the-pythonpath), but the simplest answer to your question is, in your jenkins build configuration, configure the build step with:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PATH_TO_MODULE:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: I think I got confused because it was an .egg file.  I was pointing to  the wrong place on top of this.  Thanks! :)