# Compile Android project in Continuous Integration System Hudson?

Tags: android, compilation, continuous-integration, hudson

I'm setting up a Continuous Integrations System with **Hudson** and it's just amazing.
I got a SVN repository and integrated a post-commit hook that notifies Hudson when someone commits to the repository. This part is working splendid.

The general idea is, that if the project fails, with unit-tests or anything else, it should tell the collaborator(i'm using a simple e-mail notifier atm). But if it successes I want it to compile the project and build either an unsigned or a signed **.apk** file.

What's the easiest or smartest way to do this?
I've read you can use a **Shell Command** to build the **.apk** but I can't seem to figure out how this works? Can anyone tell me how I can do this or should I go for another solution?

Thanks in advance

Finn Larsen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [guide on the Jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project) about building Android apps with Hudson or Jenkins, including building and running a test app, obtaining code coverage and static analysis stats.
Essentially you can use the Ant support built-in to build your application.

If you want to run automated tests, you can also use the [Android Emulator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin).

Since you're just starting out with Hudson, I would say now is a good time to [upgrade to Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4973981). ;)

Comment: That was a easy to switch from Hudson to Jenkins and just by reading the headings and a snippets of that thread, I'm sure it's a great Idea. I'm planing to use that plugin as well but i'm not quite there yet :P
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remeber hudson supports ant's builds. And android apps can be built using ant use [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html) for more info about building android apps with ant. Be aware that you'll have to install Android SDK on your build agent.

Answer (score 2):

Android provides ant build script. So, you can make apk easily.

1. install android-sdk in hudson server
2. install ant in hudson server ( ant version should be > 1.8 )
3. in hudson, call cmd `android update project -p <PATH to your project>`
4. in hudson, call `ant debug`. debug target generates debug apk build