# Hudson build scripts location - recommendation?

Tags: tfs, hudson, nant

I'm already finishing my project build automation :) with Hudson and Nant.

My project structure is something like

```
$/Project
  build.scripts
    script1.build
    script2.build
    build.properties.xml
  Code
    Project1
    Project2
```

So Hudson downloads from the root $/Project to the workspace folder.

And everything is ok since the build.scripts are in the workspace, I run them very easily, however what is bugging me is the fact that since the build scripts are inside the workspace, then I can't program Hudson to run automatically either based on time or changes because it will always detect changes to the files (note build.properties.xml which I check out and check in at build time to store some stats).

Where do you recommend these files to go in and still get the advantage of having them source-controlled?

Comment: I considered putting the scripts in another workspace, but TFS plugin only allows one path (though that second path will be marked as a change).

Comment: Also the Clone Workspace plugin I'd say probably also considers the cloned workspace as changes or not?

Comment: Another thing, the TFS plugin isn't updated by Hudson anymore; development moved to Jenkins. It's probably worth upgrading to Jenkins: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4973981/

Comment: upgraded to jenkins and loving it. However tfs plugin does not have this yet! hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is to NOT check-in changes to those files. I changed my CI workflow to create another file (local to the workspace only) where the changes are written to.

This way, I still get the last build info written somewhere to pick it up, and avoid the issue of Jenkins detecting the change.

PS: I changed from Hudson to Jenkins since I saw that most plugins ran away from the former. The transition was too smooth to be true.