# schedule ant task

Tags: ant, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible "and how if you know", to schedule the execution of an ant task?
For example, i want my build.xml to be executed every 5 hours or every day at a certain time?
I have been looking around but no solution found

Thank you

Comment: This depends entirely on your build environment. What operating system are you using? Do you have a dedicated build server?

Comment: hi, i'm using tomcat7 on a mac with leopard, still on my local machine

Comment: If you're already running tomcat, download and deploy the Jenkins WAR file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For very simple requirements, I'd echo the use of cron.

If the reason for running ANT is to periodically perform a master build of your project's code, then you're effectively following a practice called ["Continuous Integration"](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html). In that case I'd highly recommend running a continuous integration server, such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Jenkins is a very useful piece of software, easy to install and can become your automation framework for more than just building your code.

Comment: +1 @JBoy You can also try to use build systems like Luntbuild or TeamCity

Comment: hudson can also be a good option to schedule ant file to run with many other features

Comment: @SanjayJain Jenkins is a Hudson fork. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973981/how-to-choose-between-hudson-and-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Just use cron and call ant.sh from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a windows environment, you can use the "task scheduler" and set the interval. If you are working in unix/linux, you may use cron for scheduling your job.