# Can a Hudson job set a description of its own build?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I'm aware there is Web API allowing this trick using current build number. But it requires authentication thus script must be edited on each hudson.

Is there a way to achieve that from script or through plugin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're talking about setting the description of a build, Jenkins can do this, based on a regular expression in the build output.

See the [Description Setter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin).

Comment: Thanks, there is similar plugin for Hudson.

Comment: Perhaps, but you should upgrade; plus that plugin isn't maintained for Hudson any more. http://stackoverflow.com/q/4973981/234938