# Most suitable contious integration system for doing automatic build and deployments to jboss EAP 5.0

Tags: continuous-integration, jboss5.x, continuum

We use [Apache Continuum](http://continuum.apache.org/) for our continous builds now and it FTP's the build and uses [maven deploy/undeploy](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jboss-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) to do our builds. This has been flaky and stopped working once we upgraded to Jboss EAP 5.0 from Jboss 4.3. We are investigating the issue and planning to upgrade our installation of continuum.

In the meantime I was wondering, may be other products do it better. I'm willing to try another product if it makes our job easier in the long run. We use maven 2 and continuum has been working smoothly in terms of SCM integration and building. Configuration is pretty painless too. Our only issue is the automatic deployments.

How do other CI products like (Hudson, Cruise Control) rate in integration with Jboss? Have any of you used any other CI products with automatic deployemnts to Jboss servers (located on different machines over the network)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choosing among Jenkins, Hudson, and CruiseControl - use Jenkins. CruiseControl is on its way out. Here's the rationale [to use Jenkins over Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4973981/1178189).

Jenkins has a [JBoss Management Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JBoss+Management+Plugin).

Disclaimer: I do not have any working experience with JBoss or the plugin mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Didn't know hudson is forked by oracle now. Will look into Jenkins. If we rule out cruise control, what would you prefer between Jenkins/Hudson vs Continuum.

Comment: I have not experience with Continuum. One point for Jenkins: very easy to install, so just try it.

Comment: Hi @malenkiy_scot, haven't tried yet. But it is on the list for next sprint. Will try within next couple of weeks. :)

Comment: Hi @malenkiy_scot. I've tried Jenkins and it is quite easy to setup and get going. But it has the same problem as what I'm currently trying to solve with continuum, deploying to JBoss EAP 5.0.1. Current plugin only supports deploying to JBoss 4. With thousands of plugins though, I'm quite encouraged to give it a shot myself.