# Android Logcat files on Hudson/Jenkins

Tags: android, hudson, jenkins, emulation, logcat

we are using Hudson for CI of an Android project with Android emulator plugin to run UI tests on the emulator. A git project delivers the source code.

Now I see that in the git repo, for each build a logcat file is created and put in the git project folder, which is then pushed back to git. As we are expecting a lot of builds, this could easily spam the project folder. Does anyone know if it is possible to set the destination folder for the emulator logs?
I cannot find any options in the emulator plugin or Hudson anywhere.

The logcat files are named logcat_[some_number].log.

Best regards,
Kim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to [version 2.0 of the plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin#AndroidEmulatorPlugin-Version2.0%28December26%2C2011%29) (or newer) and you'll see these logcat files are now written to a temporary directory, rather than your workspace.

If you're using Hudson, possibly you only see the very old version 1.6 in the Update Centre.
Which is just another reason to [upgrade to Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974032/234938)! :)

However, if you can't upgrade either the plugin or Jenkins (for some weird reason), just use an "Execute shell" step to delete any `logcat_*.log` files at the start of each build.
These files are purely temporary anyway and should probably only exist in your workspace  after a failed build — otherwise the logcat output is archived automatically as `logcat.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Add an ant task to rename the logcat file to your convenience and remove the oldest ones.

Answer (score 1):

add the logs to the .gitignore file, if you want to exclude them from your repository.