# setting hudson build trigger to check for svn changes

Tags: linux, svn, hudson

i have set Poll SCM with different options
but none of them seems to work
i tried

```
* * * * * 
5 * * * *
*/10 * * * *
```

it doesn't seem to try to build
and changes were committed to the svn[image]

any idea what i'm doing wrong ?
do i have to set a post commit hook ?
shouldn't this work ?
thanks

Comment: (1) What version of SVN are you using - Hudson does not work well with 1.7 (2) Do you see anything suspicious in the System Log - http://[server]/log/all ?

Comment: SVN/1.5.4. also that url returns 404

Comment: i added a hook and it seems to work, just a bit annoyed it doesn't work without it

Comment: So it seems you did not specify the right URL or your Jenkins server is can't access it. Your second comment seems to indicate that you've solved you problem, haven't you? בהצלחה

Comment: Jenkins server ? whats that ?

Comment: I meant Hudson. [Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973981/how-to-choose-between-hudson-and-jenkins) is another 'branch' of Hudson that most people use, though. If at all possible in your organization, I'd advise migrating to Jenkins.

Comment: @malenkiy_scot can you give more details as why hudson doesn't like svn 1.7?  We are half way through upgrading to 1.7 !!!

Comment: @Neil, here we go https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11381

Comment: this was solved with a hook which i s a workaround. i still would like to know if its a bug in Hudson or if my config was wrong

Comment: Couple of other things you may want to check: go to http:/[server]/configure page and search for "subversion" and then "polling". See if any of the settings look suspicious. Go to the job that has SVN polling configured and click on "Subversion Polling Log". See what it says.

Comment: config:  Subversion Workspace Version = 1.4,  
  Subversion Revision Policy = queue time, Exclusion revprop name = empty and Validate repository URLs up to the first variable name is not checked. cant see anything with polling in it. polling log is this: Subversion Polling Log

Started on 18-Jul-2012 11:48:03
Received SCM poll call on  for adServer on 18-Jul-2012 11:48:03
http://analytics.inner-active.com:8080/svn/AdServer/trunk/inneractive-server is at revision 2,120
Done. Took 72 ms
No changes.  since it gets msgs from the hook to start