# Automatic build and push zip/tar.gz to website directory

Tags: java, git, ant, build, web

I'm trying to automate having a "nightly" build of a project of mine. I want to take the head of a git repo and compile using ant build script, then package into a zip and tar.gz then push to a directory on a website (ftp, scp, or sFtp are all file options). I think I need something like Bamboo from Altassian, but this costs too much for my hobby project at the moment. Am I on the right track and need to keep looking for something similar, is there a better way -- any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: thanks everyone. I think i'm going to go with jenkins -- it seems it was forked from Hudson at some point and are working to "improve" hudson, which is already known as great continuous integration software. Both suggestions got me googling in the right direction though! thanks again!

Comment: after further research it appears to have been yet another loss in an oracle takeover... the "core" of hudson dev team moved to jenkins and left oracle. al la mysql/mariadb, openoffice/libreoffice, java (james gosling)/google, etc. **sigh**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are free open source alternatives. you could use [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to do this, for example

Comment: Thanks for sharing new alternatives. Really helps the cause :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)

Many projects use this.

Comment: its a bit of a flame war, but hudson seems to get less development attention than jenkins. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433083/hudson-vs-jenkins-in-2012