# Jenkins - Not Showing Build History

Tags: jenkins

I have a multi-module maven project that I'm building with Jenkins called MyApp. I also have another maven project that depends on MyApp, and this project runs integration tests on MyApp.

In Jenkins, when I view the status of the MyApp project it successfully displays a list of previously run builds and I can click on them to find out more information (and view the console output).

However, the integration test project, while it does build properly, it only displays previously run builds for about 5 minutes, at which point something happens and jenkins completely forgets the build ever ran.

On the filesystem, I am able to cd to:

```
/usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/My App Integration Test/builds
```

and ls reveals

```
me@myserver:/usr/share/tomcat6/.jenkins/jobs/My App Integration Test/builds$ ls

1  2  2013-01-24_16-46-59  2013-01-24_16-51-58  2013-01-24_18-05-09  2013-01-24_18-58-46  3  4
```

that all my previously run builds are right there, where they should be.

Jenkins has a "discard old builds" feature in its project configuration page, but I obviously have it unchecked.

I'm running jenkins in tomcat6 on Ubuntu.

Help please?

Comment: Your symptoms match a reported bug in Jenkins: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-15156. If you can reproduce the issue, post your steps to the Jenkins bug tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins has resolved this issue as of 1.505 I recommend everyone upgrade who does not wish to switch from Jenkins back to Hudson.

This can be done through the GUI via Manage Jenkins->Upgrade to Latest (Note for this to work you need to have the appropriate permissions for Jenkins)

More information can be found [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Automated+Upgrade) For linux users `aptitude update` or `yum update jenkins` should also work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I have jenkins running with 1.517, still facing the issue if the number of builds goes more than 65 without discard option. Found that reload configuration bring back the build history.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue and have always been able to resolve it by following these steps:

Going to `\\[buildmachine]\C$\Jenkins\jobs\[jobname]`

1. Removing the `builds` folder.
2. Removing shortcuts to `lastStable` and `lastSuccessful`.
3. Open file `nextBuildNumber` and change the number to 1.

Then build new jobs and they no longer disappear.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Dave Bacher, this appears to be a bug in Jenkins. I switched over to Hudson and problem fixed!

Comment: I would not switch from Jenkins to Hudson, Jenkins is the newer fork. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973981/how-to-choose-between-hudson-and-jenkins