# Jenkins Loses Build History

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have been using Jenkins for about a year now and occasionally run into this issue. A build will be working fine and then seemingly at random it will lose all of my build history in the GUI.

I researched this issue and found the following question regarding it [Jenkins - Not Showing Build History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514976/jenkins-not-showing-build-history) and like user: Ring Jenkins still has all of my builds under the project's build folder, but they wont show up in the GUI.

user: Ring's solution was to migrate to Hudson. Is there any solution that does not require ditching Jenkins?

I was trying to track down the issue through Jenkins JIRA tickets but it seems to end here without resolution https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16845 they had another ticket `JENKINS-17265` open but it was closed as being a duplicate of 16845.

Comment: Version? I had same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins - Not Showing Build History](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514976/jenkins-not-showing-build-history)

Comment: @kojiro very similar questions, but the "accepted" answer for the question you link to above is very bad. His accepted answer is to stop using Jenkins and revert to Hudson. I wouldn't close this question until the previous one has the correct answer.

Comment: @OrwellHindenberg True, but that doesn't make it not-a-dupe. Hopefully folks are smart enough to pick a newer, better answer over an old, accepted one.

Comment: @kojiro not sure if this matters at all, but I actually found his answer first and since it wasn't possible for me I posted this question. After I got the correct answer from amisuno I also posted that answer/suggestion to Jenkins - Not Showing Build History.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your Jenkins to latest version, will help you!!! I had same problem, update and all OK.

You can look change log [link](http://jenkins-ci.org/changelog)

Comment: I've upgraded and will now have to wait and see if build history is ever knocked out again, but since it is addressed in the changeLog under 1.505 I'm pretty confident this will work.

Comment: @OrwellHindenberg I think that everything will be ok. -_\\

Comment: @OrwellHindenberg upgrade help you?

Comment: yeah the upgrade helped. And just for others out there I used yum update jenkins. I also made a snapshot of the pre-upgrade state in case the update caused any jobs to fail, but so far everything is working as it should :D

Comment: I had the same problem, it was gone for a while (I thought due to upgrades), but it's back now :(  Jenkins LTE 1.509.2

Comment: Coming back again. JENKINS v1.505

Comment: @plsgogame I am using version 1.539, but the problem is still there, the builds keep disappearing from the gui, but they are present in the directory. I have multiple builds setup, but it only happens for one of the builds.