# Make Hudson Successful Build Icon Blue instead of Green

Tags: hudson

I upgraded my Hudson server to the latest version, and now the successful build icon is green rather than blue.  I want it to be blue.

Before, there was an option (which I wasn't interested in) to install a plugin to make the icon green.  Now, it seems with Hudson I have no choice.

I tried going into .hudson/war/webapp/images and renaming all the "green" image files to "greenx" and renaming all the "blue" image files to "green".

*It didn't work -- the icon is still green.*

I then searched for "green.png" in my entire C drive to make sure I didn't miss any green image files.  I found some I missed, and renamed them.

*It didn't work -- the icon is still green.*

I then restarted Hudson.

*It didn't work -- the icon is still green.*

Finally, I restarted my whole computer.

*It didn't work -- the icon is still green!*

I don't know what to do now.  How can I change the green icon back to blue like it used to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say [upgrade to Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974032/234938), where this behaviour remains optional via the Green Balls plugin.

If you must use Hudson, then according to the [change](http://git.eclipse.org/c/hudson/org.eclipse.hudson.core.git/commit/?id=961404fc4f7dfb4aa83c71bad4e813b88d32b5b0) where this supposed "bug" was fixed, you can re-enable the blue balls on the global configuration page.

There should be an option called "Use blue ball as legend for success instead of green ball."

Comment: Boy, I feel positively silly.  It was that simple.  Just as you said, there was the option on the configuration page.  Thanks!

Comment: It's a weird change, so I wouldn't have thought to check for a configuration option either!