# Hudson or Jenkins for Java/.Net continuous integration?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

We are looking to incorporate continuous integration/nightly builds into the development process of two of our products. One is to be written in Java using JavaFX for interface, the other is to be written in ASP .Net MVC using C# as our coding language.

The question is pretty straightforward: considering the fact that we have those two products and we want to use the same CI server for both of them, which one would be the best pick? Are there any known issues regarding either language that we should be aware of? Considering we're a very small team, is either one considerably easier to maintain and configure than the other? Any insight will be helpful!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to choose between Hudson and Jenkins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973981/how-to-choose-between-hudson-and-jenkins)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read this : [How to choose between Hudson and Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973981/how-to-choose-between-hudson-and-jenkins)

Generally use Jenkins, it is Hudson fork with better support and have much more plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Hudson died the day the entire developer community followed Kohsuke over to Jenkins.

Jenkins power is in its plugins of which Jenkins has over 1000.  Hudson has virtually no more than the day the community stopped developing Hudson and started moving Jenkins forward.

Jenkins has a rich developer community, Hudson (owned / killed by Oracle) has one guy: no contest!

Comment: Did things change with Hudson becoming an Apache project?

Comment: Nope, Hudson is dead.