# what is difference between hudson and jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I searched on many sites but not getting right answer. I am confused between hudson and jenkins.

Please suggest me which is best for JAVA CI build and Deployment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973981/how-to-choose-between-hudson-and-jenkins)

To summarize: Use Jenkins, they provide more updates with more active community support.